# Is it possible to prevent a middle-click from opening links in a new window in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events

I managed to get what I wanted working perfectly in Chrome, but when I tried it out in IE, it failed spectacularly.

I just want to apply `e.preventDefault()` to a link, so that I can handle the click event in a different way. Unfortunately, nothing I have tried has worked, and I have been at it for hours.

I have also searched Google multiple times, re-reading some of the same Stack Overflow questions in desperation, all to no avail.

Any ideas or suggestions are appreciated.

For reference, this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/exuN5/) illustrates the issue.

```
document.getElementById('link').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

In Chrome, middle-clicking on the link does nothing, as expected. In IE, middle-clicking on it still opens it in a new window. :/

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code to prevent open a new tab on mouse middle button click.

```
document.getElementById('link').addEventListener("click", function(e){
    if( e.which == 2 ) {
      e.preventDefault();
   }
  }, false);
```

**more information :**

For information of Mouse button click this code will help you.

Left - 1

Middle - 2

Right - 3

```
$(document).mousedown(function(e){
    switch(e.which)
    {
        case 1:
            //left Click
        break;
        case 2:
            //middle Click
        break;
        case 3:
            //right Click
        break;
    }
    return true;// to allow the browser to know that we handled it.
});
```

I hope it will helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, e.preventDefault() does not stop IE11 from opening the link in a new tab, regardless of whether or not we check the 'which' property.